# SQL insert statement text editor

Tags: sql, insert, editor

I'm looking for a text editor, or maybe a complement for Notepad++ to help me when building SQL insert statements.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3);
```

I would like that when I click on `column2`, `value2` is highlighted, and vice versa.

Do you know something that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several good options: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php (PHP + APACHE + MySQL)
MySQL Workbech: http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ (MySQL, PgSQL, others)
https://www.jetbrains.com/dbe/ (More general solution)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this with SublimeText

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ at the end its a rich text editor. Its first job is make text. In programming with key and value. Notepad++ may be some error about the structere.

If you write sql without any problem about the ide. You will use Sql Server Management studio etc.